# Linux search subdirectories and among .js .py files for a specific keyword

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, grep

I am trying to search for the file/script with a specific keyword in all the sub-directories beginning from the `root` or `home directory`. My search yielded so many files, but I want to search only `.js`, `.py` types. I want to know the file name containing this `matching word`.

```
grep -name '*.js' -rl "matching word" ./
```

present output:

```
grep: invalid max count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
find start_dir -type f \( -name "*.js" -o -name "*.py" \) -exec grep -l "word" {} \;
```

It will find all .js or .py files in or under the start directory and then grep them for the given word. There's other ways, but this is my "go to" for this type of thing.

Comment: How do I redirect result of this search to a `.txt` file? I tried this? `find / -type f  \( -name '*.js' -o -name '*.py' \) -exec grep -l 'rate' {} \ -print > find_rate_files.txt;` but the result is `find: missing argument to -exec`

Comment: looks like you missed the semi colon at the end. `find start_dir -type f \( -name "*.js" -o -name "*.py" \) -exec grep -l "word" {} \; > file`. You probably don't want `-print`. At a guess you'll get each file twice once from grep and once from find.

Comment: For this command `find . -type f \( -name "*.js" -o -name "*.py" \) -exec grep -l "word" {} \; > result.txt` I am getting error as `find: paths must precede exression (-name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--include` option to filter files based on a glob pattern. For multiple globs, you can either use this option multiple times or use the brace expansion feature.

```bash
echo --include={*.js,*.py} #expands to: --include=*.js --include=*.py
grep -rl --include={*.js,*.py} 'matching word'

# use this if you can have files that can start with '--include'
grep -rl --include='*.js' --include='*.py' 'matching word'
```

Another option is to make use of `globstar` feature (assuming you don't have folders that match the globs, or you'll have to use `-d skip` to prevent directories being treated as files to be searched).

```bash
shopt -s globstar
grep -l 'matching word' **/*.js **/*.py
```